# Accessing MongoDB subdocument fields in query (Typescript and Mongoose)

Tags: mongodb, typescript, mongoose

I'm using mongoose as ODM. Let's say I have this structure of schemes.

```
const Child = new mongoose.Schema({
    field1: {
      type:String
    },
    field2: {
      type:String
    }
});


const Parent = new mongoose.Schema({
  children: {
    type: [Child]
  },
});

interface IChildDoc extends mongoose.Document {
   field1: string
   field2: string
}

interface IParentDoc extends mongoose.Document {
   children: [IChildDoc]
}

const ParentModel = mongoose.model<IParentDoc>("Parent", Parent)
```

I want to query by field1, but like this:

```
const parent = await ParentModel.findOne({children.field1 : "string"});
```

But I'm getting:

```
No value exists in scope for the shorthand property 'children'. Either declare one or provide an initializer.
```

I also tried putting `children.field1` in a string but that just results returning null and I that isn't really strongly typed

Comment: Embedded documents are queried with dot notation and you need to quote the fields when they include the dot. What is your question exactly?

Comment: Well is there a way to do it the statically typed way?

Comment: I don't expect it to be possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to query like this: `{"children.field1" : "string"}`

Comment: Yeah I know but I'm looking for statically typed solution

Comment: I dont think there is a typed solution for that.